# what is "file " datatype in java..?

Tags: java, file

```
import java.io.*;

class SplitFile    
{    
    private File fSplit;
    private int sizeInBytes;

    private int count;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {    
        Console con = System.console();

        String fileName;

        int size = 0;

        System.out.print("Enter the file name to split: ");

        fileName = con.readLine();

        System.out.print("Enter the size of the target file: ");

        size = Integer.parseInt(con.readLine());

        SplitFile sf = new SplitFile(fileName, size);

        sf.split();

    }

    public File checkFileExists(String fName)    
    {    
        File f = new File(fName);

        if (!f.exists())    
        {    
            System.out.println("File " + fName + " does not exists");

            System.exit(0);

        }

        return f;

    }

    public int validateSize(int s)    
    {    
        if (fSplit.length() < s)    
        {

            System.out.println("Invalid Size");

            System.exit(0);

        }

        return s;

    }

    public String createNextFileName()    
    {    
        ++count;

        String fileName;

        fileName = "part_" + count + "." + fSplit.getName();

        return fileName;

    }

    public SplitFile(String fName, int s)    
    {

        fSplit = checkFileExists(fName);

        sizeInBytes = validateSize(s);

        count = 0;

    }

    public void split() throws IOException

    {

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fSplit);

        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

        File fileSegment = new File(createNextFileName());

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileSegment);

        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

        int ch;

        int currentByteCount = 0;

        while ((ch = bis.read()) != -1)

        {

            bos.write(ch);

            ++currentByteCount;

            if (currentByteCount == sizeInBytes)

            {

                bos.close();

                fos.close();

                fileSegment = new File(createNextFileName());

                fos = new FileOutputStream(fileSegment);

                bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

                currentByteCount = 0;

            }

        }

        bis.close();

        fis.close();

        bos.close();

        fos.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: i have never heard about the file datatype.. please tell me about it..

Comment: What is the given code for?

Comment: File is not a data type. Did you research before asking? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Comment: sorry in 4th line it is..private File fSplit. not private String fSplit

Comment: `File` is *An abstract representation of file and directory pathnames.* JavaDoc is something that is attached to most source files and usually explains what classes are method are expected to do.

Comment: Java classes are extremely well documented. Read their documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/

Comment: this code is for file splitter

Comment: if you want people to help you, please provide a clear explanation on what you are trying to do/what you are trying to accomplish, sometimes simple questions like these could be answered by yourself by exerting a little effort on reading the documentation.

Comment: http://www.scribd.com/doc/9823728/Java-Chap5-User-Defined-Data-Types-Prof-Ananda-M-Ghosh

Answer (score 7):

based from the documentation

> An abstract representation of file and directory pathnames.

The `File` is a reference type. it is used for handling files (eg. creating)  It would be more easier for you to understand it by looking at this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

**UPDATE**

Just by looking at your comments from the previous answer I've observed that you do not know/unfamiliar with the different data types in java, there are two data types.

1. Primitive Data Types (char,int,boolean)
2. Reference Types/Object(User
       Defined classes, the Superclass `Object` and in your case, the
       `File`)

Comment: Feel free to hit the check mark ;)

Answer (score 2):

The file ***Object***, is just that, an object used for handling files, you can read on the documentation for it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html).

Comment: @pradeep.. if it is not a datatype.. then what is it..??

Comment: @joy an class which can be instantiated into an object like most things in java (EG: the string class)

Comment: ohkay.. is it a predefined class in java..?

Comment: If you are referring to the "File" object, then yes it is predefined in java.  but you can also create your own Reference type, but that is already out of scope of this question.

Comment: @joy, it's time to learn basics of Java, Oracle website has a good tutorial for the same.

Comment: thank you all.. i just read the documentation.. it is what, i was looking for.